# How to create map fields in scala from dataframes?

Tags: scala, dataframe

I have two data frames as below:

df1:

```
language (column name)
tamil
telugu
hindi
```

df2:

```
id    keywords 
101   ["tamildiary", "tamilkeyboard", "telugumovie"]
102   ["tamilmovie"]
103   ["hindirhymes", "hindimovie"]
```

Using these two data frames, I need to create something that looks like the below. (Basically, need to find how many of the language specific keywords are against each id and store them in a map)

```
id    keywords
101   {"tamil":2, "telugu":1}
102   {"tamil":1}
103   {"hindi":2}
```

Could anyone please help me in doing this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider joining the two DataFrames using `regexp_replace` to regex match for strings with a leading language-keyword, followed by a couple of `groupBy`s to aggregate an array of `(language, count)`, which then gets converted to a map via `map_from_entries`:

```
val df1 = Seq("tamil", "telugu", "hindi").toDF("language")

val df2 = Seq(
  (101, Seq("tamildiary", "tamilkeyboard", "telugumovie")),
  (102, Seq("tamilmovie")),
  (103, Seq("hindirhymes", "hindimovie"))
).toDF("id", "keywords")

val pattern = concat(lit("^"), df1("language"), lit(".*"))

df2.
  withColumn("keyword", explode($"keywords")).as("df2").
  join(df1.as("df1"), regexp_replace($"df2.keyword", pattern, lit("")) =!= $"df2.keyword").
  groupBy("id", "language").agg(size(collect_list($"language")).as("count")).
  groupBy("id").agg(map_from_entries(collect_list(struct($"language", $"count"))).as("keywords")).
  show(false)
// +---+-------------------------+
// |id |keywords                 |
// +---+-------------------------+
// |101|[tamil -> 2, telugu -> 1]|
// |103|[hindi -> 2]             |
// |102|[tamil -> 1]             |
// +---+-------------------------+
```

---

For `Spark 2.0 - 2.3`, create a UDF to mimic functionality of `map_from_entries` which is available only in `Spark 2.4+`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val arrayToMap = udf{ (arr: Seq[Row]) =>
  arr.map{ case Row(k: String, v: Int) => (k, v) }.toMap
}

df2.
  withColumn("keyword", explode($"keywords")).as("df2").
  join(df1.as("df1"), regexp_replace($"df2.keyword", pattern, lit("")) =!= $"df2.keyword").
  groupBy("id", "language").agg(size(collect_list($"language")).as("count")).
  groupBy("id").agg(arrayToMap(collect_list(struct($"language", $"count"))).as("keywords")).
  show(false)
```

---

As a side note, below are a couple of alternatives for the regex-matching condition via a SQL expression:

Using `regexp_extract`:

```
expr("regexp_extract(df2.keyword, concat('^(', df1.language, ').*'), 1) = df1.language")
```

Using `rlike`:

```
expr("df2.keyword rlike concat('^', df1.language, '.*')")
```

Comment: I am getting this error "error: not found: value map_from_entries"

Comment: @Thivagar Moorthy, [map_from_entries](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@map_from_entries(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) is available in Spark 2.4 or above.  Please see my expanded answer for older Spark versions.

Comment: Yeah did that, just one question. The result when stored in a variable is of type Unit. I should have to repartition the result. Adding ".repartition(30)" at the end is giving error. [value repartition is not a member of Unit]

Comment: The appended `.show()` is for displaying output of the transformed DataFrame, hence is of type `Unit`.  You could assign the resulting DataFrame a new value, say, `val df3 = df2.withColumn...as("keywords"))`.

Comment: Yeah did that, thanks! Now I have a different problem if you could check this pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66265153/how-to-incorporate-spark-scala-map-field-to-bq

Comment: The intermediate transformation `.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list(struct($"language", $"count")).as("app_language"))` prior to applying the UDF is probably what you're seeking.